# Caching assocations in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, caching

I'm trying to cache associations using second level cache of hibernate.
Firstly I have Department Class which stores list of users.

```
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)

public class Department {

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="department")
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public Set<User> getUsersSet() {
    return this.usersSet;
}
```

Then  I have User class which stores the department.

```
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class User{

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="department_id")
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public Department getDepartment() {
    return this.department;
}
```

I have applied cache with the associations in both Department and User classes.
This association is being stored in the cache.
    sessionFactory.getStatistics().getSecondLevelCacheHitCount() also increases if I enable cache on association. 
Department is getting cached and there is no database hit while I try to retrieve a department, however, I see a database hit every time I fetch users of a department:

```
Set<User> users = department.getUsersSet();
for (User u : users) {
   System.out.println("User name : " + u.getFirstName());
}
```

Comment: Your settings seems to be correct (as you also had experienced) The `@Cache` over `getDepartment()` is redundant though. It may be that the cache max elements is too low for the `User` cache so elements are often evicted

Comment: The second level cache contains user entries also like {201=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.internal.strategy.AbstractReadWriteEhcacheAccessStrategy$Item@41d24c6f} where 201 is the user id

Comment: True, but entities can be evicted from cahches depending on configuration

Comment: this is the setting done: timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="200", so it should not evict prior to 120 seconds